# What's the official way of programmatically changing the GDM login background?

Tags: centos, themes, gdm

I want to change the background of the GDM login screen on CentOS 6.5 and 7 to bring it in line with other branded systems, and so I have an RPM that delivers a background image into `/usr/local/share`....

I've seen various ways of getting this set as the login session's background, including running the configuration utility, launching the background picker as a login application, and some pretty hairy editing of config files.

What would the official way of doing this so that I can deploy to dozens of machines, rather than visiting each? Eventually, I want to put this into Puppet to enforce the setting, but I have no idea what I'd monitor to check it.

I'd like to leave users able to choose their own desktop background, though my next question would be about setting a default if they haven't picked one...

Comment: Depending on the version of GDM, there might be four or five different methods.

Comment: On CentOS 6.5, my default version is 2.30.4.